# Java objects and GUI

Tags: java, object, user-interface

How would I begin to write a mortgage calculator that compiles and runs, but I would be bale to add a GUI to later without re-writing the initial code

Comment: your question is too general. Have you tried something or having problems with something specific?

Comment: You should provide at least some example code with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Model-view-controller pattern.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you write your service methods which calculates mortgage as `reusable`/`decoupled`. Meaning no direct dependency on console input/output etc. Once it is there, you can either use it to work with Swing GUI/a web interface etc..